# Change row names in R Studio

Tags: r, quantmod, rbind

I've tried to change row names from date to characters;

```
library(quantmod)

mdate <- "2019-05-01"
edate <- "2019-05-08"
tickers <- c("MMM","C", "AAPL", "IBM", "AMZN")
rnames <- c("Open_1", "Open_2", "Open_3", "Open_4", "Open_D")
portfolioPrices <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers)
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,1])
  colnames(portfolioPrices) = tickers
  rownames(portfolioPrices) = rnames
```

These codes give me:

[image]

As you see, row names are not changed. I want to change them from date to `rnames <- c("Open_1", "Open_2", "Open_3", "Open_4", "Open_D")`

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: `portfolioPrices` is an `xts` object (check with `str(portfolioPrices)` and as such cannot have row names.  Per the documentation (`?dimnames.xts`) "xts objects by design are intended for lightweight management of time-indexed data.  Rownames are redundant in this design, as well as quite burdensome with respect to memory consumption and internal copying costs."

Comment: Thank you for the information. Then, can you let me know to add rnames to a new column right next to the dates?  I used cbind, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "tk_tbl" function from "timetk" package to convert the xts object to a data frame.

```
library(quantmod)
library(timetk)

mdate <- "2019-05-01"
edate <- "2019-05-08"
tickers <- c("MMM","C", "AAPL", "IBM", "AMZN")
rnames <- c("Open_1", "Open_2", "Open_3", "Open_4", "Open_D")

portfolioPrices <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers)
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,1])

#tk_tbl convert "xts" object to data frame, but the original dates will be transformed into a new column named "index" 
timetk::tk_tbl(portfolioPrices)
   # A tibble: 5 x 6
      index      MMM.Open C.Open AAPL.Open IBM.Open AMZN.Open
      <date>        <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
    1 2019-05-01     189.   70.7      210.     141.     1933.
    2 2019-05-02     184.   69.7      210.     140.     1913.
    3 2019-05-03     186.   70.4      211.     140.     1949 
    4 2019-05-06     182.   69.1      204.     138.     1918.
    5 2019-05-07     182.   69.3      206.     139.     1940.

#remove the "index" column and reassign colnames and rownames
portfolioPrices <- timetk::tk_tbl(portfolioPrices)[, -1] 
colnames(portfolioPrices) = tickers
rownames(portfolioPrices) = rnames
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!